# Using the lubridate package on Windows and Mac interchangeably

Tags: r, windows, macos, lubridate

the following problem certainly doesn't only apply to the `lubridate` package and maybe this has been discussed elsewhere. Unfortunately, I don't know how to ask my question in a more generic way. Therefore here with the `lubridate` example:

I have a database in Excel that includes dates written in Dutch in the following format:

> dd/month/yyyy (e.g. 15 Maart 2017)

Now I can use the `dmy()`command from `lubridate` with specifying `locale = 'Dutch'` on Windows. On a mac in need to specifcy `locale = 'nl_NL'` to not receive an error message.

Since I work on both systems (Windows and mac) interchangeably I am curious to find out if there is a way to avoid changing this code manually. I was thinking of `try` or `tryCatch`. I could also work with `if` statements and specify in earlier lines whether I work on a Windows or mac. But the latter would also require a manual entry from the user which I would like to avoid.

Thanks a lot for you help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention:

> But the latter would also require a manual entry from the user

That is not necessarily true, you could for example do the following:

```
if(grepl("windows",Sys.info()[['sysname']],ignore.case = T))
{
  my_locale='Dutch'
} else
{
  my_locale='nl_NL'
}
```

and then specify:

```
locale = my_locale
```

Your code should now work on Windows and Mac. However this will likely fail when you switch to Linux for example. So I wonder if there are better solutions.. Anyway, hope this helps!